# SQLServer using too much memory

Tags: memory-management, sql-server-2008-r2, local, database

I have installed on my desktop machine (with windows 7) SQLServer 2008 R2 Express.
I have only one local server running (./SQLEXPRESS) but the sqlserver process is taking ALL the RAM possible.

With an machine with 3GB of RAM the things starts to get slow, so I limited the maximun amount of RAM in the server, and now, constantly the SQLServer give some error messages that the memory is not enought. It's using 1GB of RAM with only one LOCAL server with 2 databases completely empty, how 1GB of RAM isn't enought ?

When the process start it's using an really acceptable amount of memory (around 80MB) but it's keep increasing until it reaches the maximun defined and start to complain about having not enought memory available. In that point I have to restart the server to use it again.

I have read about an hotfix to solve one of the errors I got from sqlserver:

```
There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query
```

But it's already installed on my sqlserver.

Why it's using so much memory?

Comment: Please show the queries that you are executing that result in this error message. Also post their actual execution plans.

Comment: I don't have the queries, the local database is just for Unit Test of an web application, so the queries are really obfuscated under many layers of code.
But for example if I let the server running for some time (more than 2 hours) I have problems only for trying to refresh my server on SQLServer Management Studio

Comment: I don't think the problem is with SQL Server. SQL Server does not leak memory internally, at least not for well-tested code-paths. I don't think this question can be answered without a lot more information. Capture the SQL queries with SQL Profiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can try configuring the 'max server memory' configuration option:

For additional details check:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178067(v=sql.105).aspx
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321363
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/df51cd87-68ce-439a-87fa-d5e5cd93ab31

Comment: I'm already using that... and the errors of unavailable memory occurs exactly when the SQLServer reaches the maximum amount of memory used.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem like this. 
You can increase the cache size of DB.
On MSSQL server properties, choose memory, there have "maximum server memory (in MB)" You can increase this cell.

Or same thing with query:

EXEC  sp_configure'Show Advanced Options',1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXEC  sp_configure'max server memory (MB)',3500;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO